# Is it wrong to fetch an API without using the useEffect Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I've been doing it this way but some colleges told me that I should use the `useEffect` Hook instead. The problem is that I don't see the benefit of that approach and I think that my approach is cleaner.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const fetchTheApi = () =>
  new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res({ title: "Title fetched" }), 3000));

const UseEffectlessComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  !data && fetchTheApi().then(newData => setData(newData));
  return <h1>{data ? data.title : "No title"}</h1>;
};

const UseEffectComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTheApi().then(newData => setData(newData));
  }, []);
  return <h1>{data ? data.title : "No title"}</h1>;
};

const MyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <UseEffectlessComponent />
    <UseEffectComponent />
  </div>
);
```

**Edit based on responses:**

I changed the code to re render, like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const fetchTheApi = (origin) => {
    console.log('called from ' + origin);
    return new Promise((res) =>
        setTimeout(() => res({ title: 'Title fetched' }), 3000)
    );
};

const UseEffectlessComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    !data &&
        fetchTheApi('UseEffectlessComponent').then((newData) => setData(newData));
    return <h1>{data ? data.title : 'No title'}</h1>;
};

const UseEffectComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTheApi('UseEffectComponent').then((newData) => setData(newData));
    }, []);
    return <h1>{data ? data.title : 'No title'}</h1>;
};

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    counter < 3 && setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter + 1), 1000);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>counter is: {counter}</p>
            <UseEffectlessComponent />
            <UseEffectComponent />
        </div>
    );
};
```

In the console I got:

`called from UseEffectlessComponent
called from UseEffectComponent
called from UseEffectlessComponent
called from UseEffectlessComponent
called from UseEffectlessComponent`

So, I finally found the benefit to that approach. I've got some code to change... Thanks a lot for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, if your component re-renders before it has set the data it will attempt to fetch the data again leading to multiple fetches. Considering you only want to fetch data once and not accidentally multiple times it would be better to put it in the useEffect.

Answer (score 4):

How you've written it does work, kind of. You're saying "If the fetch fails and the component re-renders, then try again, else don't". Personally I think that is an unreliable system - depending on a re-render to try again, and can easily have unintended side-effects:

- What if your data is falsy? What if it fails (which you didn't handle). In this case it will keep trying to re-fetch.
- What if the parent renders 3 times in a row (a very common situation). In that case your fetch will happen 3 times before the first fetch is complete.

So with that in mind you actually need more careful checks to ensure you code doesn't have unexpected consequences by not using useEffect. Also if your fetch wanted to re-fetch on prop changes your solution also doesn't work.

Comment: But he got a condition on `data`, it won't fetch every render, or am I wrong? (Although I totally agree on everything else, it's just a particular case of fetching once).

Answer (score 0):

You should use useEffect, because what you do is anti-pattern. From react's website you can clearly see why useEffect is there:

> Data fetching, setting up a subscription, and manually changing the
>   DOM in React components are all examples of side effects. Whether or
>   not you’re used to calling these operations “side effects” (or just
>   “effects”), you’ve likely performed them in your components before.
>   https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

React components are just functions, takes some props and returns some jsx. If you want to have a side effect, you shouldn't have it directly in your component. It should be in a lifecycle method.

Image your condition check (!data), was a complex one looping over arrays etc. It'd have a bigger performance impact. But useEffect will be more performant and you can even use the second argument for kind of 'caching' results.

There is **technically no difference** between your two components, except the condition check will run on every render in your version. Whereas useEffect will be called only in 'mounted', 'updated' states of the component.